# SQL: Оптимальный способ хранить данные, которые должны быть уникальные по трем колонкам

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть следующая задача:

Необходимо создать таблицу, которая будет содержать некоторые данные о транзакциях. Есть одно ограничение - эта таблица не должна иметь дубликатов. Дубликаты - это записи, у которых значения трех колонок совпадают (`MachineID`, `BeginSaleDate`, `EndSaleDate`).

Вот что я накидал:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction]
(
    [TransactionID]    INT                  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [MachineID]        VARCHAR(10)          NOT NULL,
    [BeginSaleDate]    DATETIMEOFFSET(7)    NOT NULL,
    [EndSaleDate]      DATETIMEOFFSET(7)    NOT NULL,
    -- Есть другие поля, я их опустил

    CONSTRAINT [uc_Transaction_MachineID_BeginSaleDate_EndSaleDate] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
        [MachineID] ASC,
        [BeginSaleDate] ASC,
        [EndSaleDate] ASC
    ) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
)
```

Затем предстоит реализовать вставку записи в эту таблицу. Планируется, что в эту таблицу будет вставляться достаточно много записей (за 1 час может вставляться порядка 1000 записей). В связи с этим **вопрос**: оправдано ли создавать индекс, проверяющий уникальность записи при вставке, если записей будет вставляться много в эту таблицу? Не прогорю ли я в будущем на большом времени вставки записи? Если я все же буду терять много времени на вставках, какие есть альтернативы?

Comment: 1 запись реже чем в 3 секунды - это разве много? ))  А за какой период там в итоге данные планируется держать? Со временем то много записей может накопиться, и тогда возможно записи будут не так быстро уже вставляться.

Comment: Составной уникальный индекс оправдан. Он собственно для этого и был сделан ) Главное не забывать обрабатывать исключения, если вдруг будут попадаться дубли

Comment: @CrazyElf записи там будут накапливаться со временем. Каждый день, каждый час будет приходить файл, который может содержать тысячи таких транзакций, которые сразу же придется записать в таблицу. Глядишь, через три месяца может накопиться пару миллионов записей. Я просто думаю, стоит ли заводить индекс, либо обойтись обычной проверкой на уникальность перед вставкой без использования индекса.

Comment: Пара миллионов - это вообще ни о чём. *стоит ли заводить индекс* Заводить - да. Сомневаться о целесообразности этого - нет.

Comment: Если у вас будет пара миллионов записей и приедет файл с 10000 транзакций, то что бы проверить уникальность, вам придется выбрать данные из таблицы по **каждой** транзакии. Если индексов нет, то на каждый селект вы получите **FULL SCAN** таблицы. Вот это будет оооочень долго и так 10000 раз!

Comment: Всем спасибо за обратную связь! Если есть желание у кого-либо, можете оформить ответ, я отмечу его галочкой

Comment: В общем, индекс плох только в том случае, если у вас точно уникальные записи и вы разом всю таблицу на миллионы записей хотите заполнить. Тогда имеет смысл отключить индекс на время этой массовой записи, чтобы она прошла быстрее. Но потом индекс всё-равно включают. Индексы - это хорошо.